# Htaccess - RewriteRule, how to keep only the value part of a query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite an url from:

```
https://www.website.com/test/test-detail?name=abc
```

to:

```
https://www.website.com/test/abc
```

I can't seem to find a way to keep only the value part of the query string.

This is the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test/test-detail/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=
RewriteRule ^(test)/(test-detail)/$ /test/$3 [R=301,L]
```

For the input:

```
https://website.com/test/test-detail/?name=abc
```

The result is:

```
https://website.com/test/?name=abc
```

[Link to the example.](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=92d004d9-f49d-4e11-93c2-5ba4ecb4d78a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test/test-detail/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(test)/(test-detail)/$ /test/%1?  [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser's cache before you test this.